# How can I change the Crystal Report version in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, shared-hosting

I'm getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Crystal Reports is not working on shared server hosting even hosting provider providing Crystal Reports. They providing Crystal Reports 13.0.21.2533.

Please help me - how can I change my current Crystal Reports version according to hosting version?

Thanks

[Screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i4MW.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the contents of your image/link to your question. It will make it easier for others to research your errors. Also your question may get down voted, which makes it harder to quality responses (some may ignore questions with a negative score)

Comment: Thank you. i edited and more clear question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Open IIS
- Go to current server – > Application Pools
- Select the application pool your 32-bit application will run under
- Click Advanced setting or Application Pool Default
- Set Enable 32-bit Applications to True

Comment: Cannot able to access IIS, because i'm using shared server hosting. 
please provide solution in hosting context.